# React Native Firebase: error reading data from firebase

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read data from firebase in componentDidMount(), but the reading was not going well.

The `alert('hello')` will be always shown.

I notice that sometimes the reading works, sometimes not and I don't know why.

Code

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.isNewUser('+44123123123');
}

isNewUser = (phoneNumber) =>{

  alert('hello');
  let userRef = firebase.database().ref('users/'+phoneNumber);

  userRef.on('value', (snapshot)=> {
    let value = snapshot.val();
    console.log(value);

    if(snapshot.exists())
      alert('not new');
    else 
      alert('it is new');
    });
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without some more information on the case where the code doesn't do what you expect it to do. I'd definitely change `on(...` to `once(...`. While I don't think that's the reason for your question, it'll solve some problems in the future as you seem to expect that `isNewUser()` checks only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add
`console.warn(value);`. If it results with `null` then the node doesn't exist in the database.